# Javascript history.back not working

Tags: javascript

I built a facebook tab which has a form to fill out. However below the form there is a link to a terms and conditions page which sits on a different URL from the form.

The form is on: page/like 
and the T&C page is on page/terms

In the T7C page there is a back button which inside the href has the following:

```
 href="javascript:window.history.back()"
```

and this button suppose to bring you back to the form after you have red the T&C.

This works fine on a testing server, however as soon as it's embedded in facebook the back button stops working and it doesn't go back to the form but to the home page of the brand.

The other issue that I have just came across is the if I fill out some of the fields and then I click on the T&C page and go back to the form using the back button the input fields are all empty.

Is there a way front-end side that this can be fixed too?

Comment: its possible that the anchor click is causing the history to increment by one. (just a hunch)

Answer (score 3):

Does the console tell you anything?

Try `window.history.go(-1);`.

Alternatively, have you tried opening the T&C in a separate window using `target="_blank"`? If you are worried about making sure the terms are read, inside the opened window, you may be able to run a function in the parent window using `window.opener.readTC()`, where `.readTC` is your function.

Comment: It seems to be that there is a bug in Chrome about this back button thing, I am not sure if it's related to facebook or google chrome itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function goBack()
  {
  window.history.back()
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()">

</body>
</html>
```